# Using Filesystemwatcher to rename a monitored file to a directory one level higher than it's own directory

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I have a script that will use filesystemwatcher to monitor a folder and it's subdirectories for a new file. Once it detects the new file, it will then rename the file to the directory that the file was placed in.

It works great however the usecase has slightly changed. Instead of a file being copied into the monitored subdirectory, a folder that contains the file is being placed into the monitored directory. the file is detected however, the file is renamed to the folder it was sent in, instead of the directory the folder is placed in.

example:

```
    monitored_directory
            monitored_subdirectory#1
                   new_folder       
                   new_file.txt

    new_file.txt becomes new_folder.txt

                instead of

    monitored_subdirectory#1.txt
```

Heres what i have so far:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.Path = 'C:\monitored_directory'
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action =
{
    $path = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changetype = $event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $destination = 'C:\Detected\'
       
        Get-ChildItem C:\monitored_directory -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination { "$($destination)$($_.Directory.Name+'.txt')" } 
         
}
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher 'Created' -Action $action
```

Placing a folder into the "monitored_directory" folder, will result in the file being named after the wrong folder.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, what you want is `$_.Directory.Parent.Name` instead of `$_.Directory.Name`

Comment: Ha!. Is it that easy? Obviously I'm not very good at scripting. So i just looked it up and I feel silly because I assumed parent was somehow in reference to the root directory when in fact, it's the directory just above. Is that correct?

Comment: You're correct, the [`.Parent` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.parent?view=net-7.0#system-io-directoryinfo-parent) refers to that literally haha, the _"parent of this folder"_ :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon lol makes sense. Also, I just tried adding the ".parent" dot notation and it is doing the same thing.. So just changing that isn't enough? Is there something additional I need to do?

Comment: like this `-Destination { "$($destination)$($_.Directory.Parent.Name+'.txt')" }` ? that should work fine I think

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon yeah i just tried it twice but for some reason it just ignores the .Parent notation... what you say makes sense. I'll keep trying.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon hold on a sec, I think I had another instance open and seemed to be giving me false readings.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Success! Wow, so simple. Thank you!! Also, Thanks for the help awhile back with the runspaces. You do awesome work my friend!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :) it's my pleasure

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon What if I need to go one level above the .Parent directory? I tried .Parent.Parent.Name but that isn't working... Is this also simple, or should I post another question.

Comment: `.Directory.Parent.Parent.Name` sounds about right. If that's not working then the issue might be something else like permissions to copy to that folder or something else

Comment: Ok that might be it. I'll look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who needs the answer it's simply changing the dot notation from `.Directory.Name` to [`.Directory.Parent.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.parent?view=net-7.0#system-io-directoryinfo-parent):

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.Path = 'C:\monitored_directory'
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action =
{
    $path = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changetype = $event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $destination = 'C:\Detected\'
       
    Get-ChildItem C:\monitored_directory -Filter *.txt -Recurse |
        Copy-Item -Destination { "$($destination)$($_.Directory.Parent.Name+'.txt')" } 
}
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher 'Created' -Action $action
```